# ruby equal sign in method call

Tags: ruby, syntax

Hi there fellow rubyists!
I've just came across a weird syntax in method call:

```
Foo.bar 'first_arg', more1='other', more2='another'
```

but when I test it out `'other'` is always assigned to the second argument, never mind the word before equal sign. What is this? Why is this in ruby? I'm familiar with ruby 2.0 key-arguments, but this seems to have nothing to do with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'other'` is assigned to the variable `more1` and the resulting expression is always `'other'` so that value is passed to the `bar` method. So why do that? Well, probably `more1` and `more2` are used after that call. I don't like it but that's it.

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with key arguments.

This is just a shortcut of assigning and passing variables to the method.

```
Foo.bar 'first_arg', more1='other', more2='another'
```

Can be rewritten as

```
more1='other'
more2='another'
Foo.bar('first_arg', more1, more2)
```

Comment: Indeed, nothing to do with kwargs.

Comment: _"Can be rewritten"_ – Can, and should, be rewritten.

Comment: @Stefan I see a trail of fighting rubocop’s “method body’s too long” cop here :)